# Is my app allowed to post as a Facebook page using API without human interaction after the latest policy changes? (since April 24, 2018)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add a feature to my web application where my (business) customers can promote their weekly deals automatically using my webapp.

I had this feature already, but before I could start with it the April change happened and now I'm unsure if I would be rejected in the review process.

What I'd like to do is:

1. User authorizes my WebApp with manage_pages and publish_pages
2. The app converts the short-time token into a long lived token
3. The user selects one of his pages as target for the deal postings
4. When the deals should be announced, the system creates a posting with generated text and a link to the deals (in my webApp)

The text regarding the review guidelines is not clear for me, as it seems to contradict itself a bit.

Is that still allowed or do I have to force the users to generate these postings manually?

Comment: i would say your use case was never allowed, as the user does not have full control over what exactly gets posted. you are talking about "deals" that will get posted without his interaction, right? no scheduled posts of the user, just random stuff.

Comment: Well, the user has weekly deals that he publishes on my site and the generated post contains a brief more or less static text plus a link to the page with these deals. So he has no direct control, but knows what is posted, because he can preview that

Comment: so only his own deals will get posted, and he knows exactly what and when it gets posted?

Comment: Right, it's just done automatically

Comment: I have a similar use case (auto-posting updates from a website to a public Facebook page). I tried to pass the App Review today, and discovered that such thing was apparently never allowed in the first place (*Apps won't be approved for this use of publish_pages*), just like @luschn said.

Comment: @Retif I'm a bit confused. Luschn wrote that it's very likely to be allowed that content from the user can be created from other servers on behalf of the user in a scheduled way. Is that different from your app that got denied?

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen, in my case I used the app myself only once (in order to get the access token), and I created the app only for that, it is not meant to be used by any other Facebook user. After that I was just publishing stuff from my website to a Facebook page where I'm an admin. And as I understood, Facebook doesn't actually allow that, so I won't pass the App Review with [such a use-case](https://retifrav.github.io/images/dotnet-core-publish-some/facebook/no-approve.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only post deals of the user itself, and he knows WHAT gets posted and WHEN, then this should be no problem. You just have to store an Extended Page Token. And of course you need to go through the review process to make your App public.

Comment: Hmm, I hope you are right :-) It would be neat to get some kind of official answer from facebook before I have to put in the effort to create the feature though

Comment: stackoverflow is for third party developers, there are facebook employees here, commenting once in a while, but it´s not an official support channel ;) - your use case is quite simple, a lot of tools offer that functionality and still work.

Comment: I know that and I'm grateful for your answer. Nevertheless, Facebooks Dev area mentions Stackoverflow as replacement for their own Dev-support system and especially the review process is documented only partial without a way to contact someone easily. So my weak hope is that there still might be someone from FB being able to confirm your well educated guess (which would be neat) or maybe confirm my suspicion (which I hope doesn't happen)

Comment: it´s not a guess, a lot of businesses and tools would not work anymore if it would be a problem ;) - as long as the user knows exactly what gets posted and when, there is no problem. you should add the relevant part of the review guidelines though. the part that is unclear.

Comment: Now the guidelines explicitly state that users need to MANUALLY enter the content or copy & paste it. No auto-generation of content without the user being actively involved in the content creation process. Have you seen this guideline for publish_pages permission? I am asking because my app just got rejected as well.

Comment: looks like they just made it more clear, but the rule was always that way. although, i am not sure how that would be a proble for your own page, to be honest...